# how can i make this code eventually prints a statement that tells whether there is at least one match or the file does not exist?

Tags: java, android, file, recursion, depth

here what I am trying to do is to print a final statement to tell whether the file was found or not. I have tried boolean flags but did not work with me because of the recursion way of doing it. and I need the solution using recursion only. this is the code:

```java
   public static void searchForFile(File dir, String target) {
        // If dir is not a directory, return
        if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Path is not a directory.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // Check each item in the directory
        for (File folderItem : dir.listFiles()) {
            // Recurse if it's a directory
            if (folderItem.isDirectory()) {
                searchForFile(folderItem,target);
            } else {
                // If it's a file, check for a match
                if (folderItem.getName().equals(target)) {
                    System.out.println(folderItem.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // The root folder to search
        File rootFolder = new File("/Users/markDev/Desktop/path");
        searchForFile(rootFolder, "test.txt");
    }
```

Comment: I guess the problem if you are not getting the way to print when it is false right? Because printing true (as it is found) you can do int when folderItem.getName().equals(target) is true

Comment: what do you mean by do int?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using recursion, you should return in this condition `!dir.isDirectory` instead of exiting like this `System.exit(0);`

if you want to print the parent folder of each match, you should use `folderItem.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()`

```
    public static void searchForFile(File dir, String target) {
        // If dir is not a directory, return
        if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
            return;
        }

        // Check each item in the directory
        for (File folderItem : dir.listFiles()) {
            // Recurse if it's a directory
            if (folderItem.isDirectory()) {
                searchForFile(folderItem,target);
            } else {
                // If it's a file, check for a match
                if (folderItem.getName().equals(target)) {
                    System.out.println(folderItem.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it fixes your problem :)

Comment: this code won't print each directory that matches the file that I am searching!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The root folder to search
        File rootFolder = new File("/Users/markDev/Desktop/path");
        searchForFile(rootFolder, "test.txt");
}


private static boolean searchFile(File file, String search) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        for (File f : files) {
            boolean found = searchFile(f, search);
            if (found)
                return true;
        }
    } else {
        if (search.equals(file.getName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```